# OneToMany issue in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have models like this:

```
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

 @Column(name="firstname")
 private String firstname;


  // and others 

    @ManyToOne( targetEntity = Employee.class,
      fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="department_id", 
            insertable=false, updatable=false, 
            nullable=false)
 private Department department;
```

=============================================================================

```
  @Table(name="DEPARTMENT")
  public class Department {

    @Column(name="DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Long departmentId;


   @OneToMany( targetEntity = Employee.class,
        fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name="department_id")
   @IndexColumn(name="idx")
   private List<Employee> employees;
```

and my DepartmentDaoImpl is

```
  public class DepartmentDaoImpl implements DepartmentDao{
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
  @Transactional
  public void addDepartment(Department department) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(department);
}
```

when i run project this exception appear in output

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.springmvc.form.Department
```

what is this problem and how solved it?

```
 Department department = new Department();
    department.setDepartmentName("Sales");
    department.setDepartmentId(90);

    Employee emp1 = new Employee("reza", "Mayers", "101",department.getDepartmentId());
   // Employee emp2 = new Employee("ali", "Almeida", "2332");

    department.setEmployees(new ArrayList<Employee>());
    department.getEmployees().add(emp1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many problems in this code.

First problem: Unknown entity: org.springmvc.form.Department. This means that Department is not annotated with @Entity and/or is not listed in the entities in the hibernate configuration file.

Second problem:

```
@ManyToOne( targetEntity = Employee.class)
private Department department;
```

This doesn't make sense. The target entity is obviously Department, not Employee. targetEntity is useless unless the type of the field is an abstract class or interface, and you need to tell Hibernat what it should use as concrete entity class. Otherwise, Hibernate know the target entity from the type of the field.

Third problem:

```
@OneToMany( targetEntity = Employee.class,
    fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="department_id")
```

This OneToMany is the inverse side of the bidirectional association that you have already declared and mapped in Employee. So you MUST NOT repeat the mapping here. Instead, you MUST declare it as the inverse side, using the `mappedBy` attribute:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@IndexColumn(name="idx")
private List<Employee> employees;
```

Using eager fetching for a toMany association is a really bad idea as well. You really don't want to load the 200 employees of a department every time you load a department. That will kill the performance of your application.

Comment: i change my code now this exception appear  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexCollectionEventListener.processCollectionEvent(Lorg/hibernate/event/AbstractCollectionEvent;)V

Comment: That's a classpath problem. You're using a version of Hibernate search that is not compatible with your version of hibernate core (presumably).

Comment: Probably because the employee's department field is null.

Comment: thanks a lot.My problem was solved. Do not insert department_id into Employee table depends on @JoinColumn(name="department_id", 
            insertable=false, updatable=false, 
            nullable=false) ?

Comment: If you make it non-insertable, then indeed inserts won't insert data in this column. That's the whole point. Same for updatable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64581/discussion-between-hadi-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: i change this @JoinColumn(name="department_id", insertable=true, updatable=false, nullable=true) but not inserted foreign key in Employee table. what? please help me.

Comment: Probably because the `department` field in your the object of type Employee that you're trying to save, is null, as I already said.

Comment: I could not insert foreign key into employee yet?what is my problem?

Comment: You still haven't shown the code inserting the employee, and you still haven't confirmed that the employee department was not null. I'm not a wizard. I can't debug code I don't see.

Comment: i must insert employee separately?

Comment: No. But if you want the employee to have a department, you shouldn't set its department to null. Otherwise, obviously, it won't have a department, and the corresponding foreign key will be set to null.

Comment: Remove that useless departmentId field from Employee, and set its department: `emp1.setDepartment(department)`.